# Pyspark - AttributeError: 'UserDefinedFunction' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, attributeerror

I created python file (python_file.py) with a function and then called the function as a UDF in pyspark-shell in the same scope. The Code is as follows

```
import python_file as outer
pyspark_func = udf(outer.my_funct, StringType())
df1 = df.select(pyspark_func(col('col1')))
```

It resulted in

AttributeError: 'UserDefinedFunction' object has no attribute '_get_object_id' error.

Can anybody please explain me the error. And is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with this code.while query dataframe Spark Sql we have to follow has given format

> Actual Data

```
+--------+---+----+
|    date| id|name|
+--------+---+----+
| 05FEB12|101|John|
| 19APR13|102|Mike|
|19APR17s|103|Anni|
+--------+---+----+
```

> UDF Creation and Registration

```
def userDefinedMethod(sample):
    return sample+"is my Name"

userDefinedMethod = udf(userDefinedMethod, StringType())

**dataDf.select(dataDf["id"],dataDf["name"],userDefinedMethod(dataDf["name"]).alias("Modified name")).show()**
```

> Resultant Output:

```
+---+-----------------+
| id|Incremental value|
+---+-----------------+
|101|   Johnis my Name|
|102|   Mikeis my Name|
|103|   Anniis my Name|
+---+-----------------+
```

Comment: How does this relate to the question? Does it really solve the problem?

Comment: Yes. Even i faced the same issue when i am trying to query data frame using like this query--> "df1 = df.select(pyspark_func(col('col1')))" and Error caused due to userdefined udf funtion are not register temporally or permanent